# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types. error

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am getting error as

> Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

at line

```
txtdate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(objPridr2["MST_DATE"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Trim();
```

how to resolve this

Comment: There are at least 10 duplicates for this same error on the related column on the right. Why you don't search before asking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
txtdate.Value = objPridr2["MST_DATE"] is DBNull ? 0 : Convert.ToDateTime(objPridr2["MST_DATE"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way using null checking

```
if(objPridr2["MST_DATE"] != System.DBNull.Value )
{
    txtdate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(objPridr2["MST_DATE"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Trim();
}
```